# How to animate items in react while changing the url?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a panel on the left hand side of my app.

On the right side, the admin can select a 'User Name'. Once the User Name is selected, i need to get categories of the selected user. From the displayed categories, I can chose one for which it will display all the items.

```
User Name > categories > items
```

I also want my url to change accordingly like `localhost/users/categories/items`

The left side will not change at all in this process, hence I do not want to re-render it. At present I have three pages, with the navigation configured.

Actually I want to place some animations on the right side as an option is clicked. The alternative i found was to define onClick and change the component with some animation - but this kind of does not allow me to change the url.

What is the best way to handle this?

I am using next-js in my react application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The alternative i found was to define onClick and change the component with some animation...

That's a correct approach.

> ...but this kind of does not allow me to change the url.

You can user browser's [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to manipulate url without page reload.

---

For instance

```
const state = {};
const pageTitle = 'My Item';
const url = 'users/categories/items';
history.pushState(state, pageTitle, url);
```

If you have `<a href's />` in your page, you might want to override their behaviour too, otherwise they'll trigger a page reload as well.